# Objective-C: Set another UITableViewCell on select

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have two custom models of `TableViewCell`, one for just basic informations and another for detailed informations.

How can I switch to the detailed one with the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method? (and afterwards if the detailed one is displayed, toggle to the basic one on select)

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by switch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the row is selected, toggle a flag indicating that the row needs to switch from one type of cell to another. Then reload the the cell at that index path.

Then your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method looks at the flag for the given index path and returns one of the two types of cells.

Answer (score 0):

In whatever kind of object you use to represent cell data, keep a flag for whether it's selected or not.  Turn the flag on or off in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and then reload the table view data.  When you return a cell for an index path, choose which kind of cell based on the flag value.

Comment: No need to reload the whole table for a single row.

Comment: Reasonable, though if you're selecting something new, you're probably also de-selecting something else...so it might be the simplest approach as long as cell populating isn't too much overhead.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array or set consist of indexPaths of cells type 1. Add or remove from it cells if needed. Return the right cell in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

And if you want to reload specific cell, modify your array of cells and just call from tableView:

`- (void)reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths
              withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation`